# oracle temporary ora 12505 error after linux startup

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-xe

I am experiencing a very strange behavior with oracle, maybe somebody can help me, let me summarize it real quick:

My OS of choice is debian linux, I am using Oracle XE 11.0.2.0. On linux startup, I run a script file which is located under /etc/init.d/. I added the following line to make oracle start on system start:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
```

Right after this line , I run my application from the script, my application heavily relies on the oracle db, therefore once oracle starts, I am positive that my application will run ok. Unfortunately my assumption seems wrong.Here's why: I set up similar set up in 3 machines, in 2 of them I see weird behavior, after system start oracle db is not responding to connection requests, Even though oracle-xe start command completed executing.

My observation is the following, if I run my application right after oracle-xe start is executed, I receive ora-12505 errors at least for a minute: "TNS listener does not currently know of SID" . After a minute everything stabilizes, and my application starts working ok. 1 minute without a db on system startup is not acceptable for me performance-wise, therefore I am trying to solve this problem.

Surprisingly it does not happen in one of the other linux boxes I have here, I am not quite sure what is different on that box. I compared ora files, but couldn't find any difference, it seems like a wild goose chase...

I would be so grateful if anybody has experienced and solved ths problem before and shares that valuable solution with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, looks like I am starting oracle-xe instance before I assign network interfaces an IP address, in that case it takes some time for oracle to receive connections, that requires me to set static ip on the linux boxes, which is something I don't want. Is there a solution so that I can still assign IP addresses later on?